# Should I be using another function other than `map_or_else` in the following?

Tags: rust

In the following code, I created a `CommandError` enum to handle two kinds of errors: `ExecutionError` and `NonZeroExit`.

I also created a `run_command` function that either returns an `Output` or a `CommandError`.

The `NonZeroExit` or `Output` is handled by `map_or_else`.

```
fn create_execution_error(err: io::Error) -> CommandError {
    CommandError::ExecutionError { source: err }
}

fn handle_output(output: Output) -> Result<Output, CommandError> {
    if output.status.success() {
        Ok(output)
    } else {
        Err(CommandError::NonZeroExit {
            status: output.status,
            stderr: output.stderr,
            stdout: output.stdout,
        })
    }
}

fn run_command(command: &str) -> Result<Output, CommandError> {
    Command::new("sh")
        .arg("-c")
        .arg(command)
        .output()
        .map_err(|err| create_execution_error(err))
        .and_then(|output| handle_output(output))
}

pub fn center_window(window_id: &str) {
    let command = format!("xdotool windowmove {} 780 400", window_id);

    run_command(&command).map_or_else(
        |err| {
            eprintln!("Command: {}", command);
            eprintln!("Error: \n{}", err);
        },
        |_| (),
    )
}
```

As you can see, I had to write `|_| ()` in the second closure of `map_or_else`—because I'm not using any arguments or returning anything.

This makes me wonder: should I be using `map_or_else`? Or maybe I should be using another function?

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f1b6e5001e899f3443dafbefae89d665)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use a simple `if let` here:

```rust
if let Err(err) = run_command(&command) {
    eprintln!("Command: {}", command);
    eprintln!("Error: \n{}", err);
}
```

There is no need to use `map_*` functions if you don't use their result.

Comment: This is also more idiomatic when the callback function has side-effects - `map` and related methods suggest to the reader that it does some transformation of data, rather than an IO operation.

Answer (score 2):

> This makes me wonder: should I be using `map_or_else`? Or maybe I should be using another function?

I'd prefer using `.map_err(..)` to log your error and call `.ok()` afterwards to avoid the warning that you must use the returned value from your expression:

```rust
run_command(&command)
    .map_err(|err| {
        eprintln!("Command: {}", command);
        eprintln!("Error: \n{}", err);
    })
    .ok();
```